# Does Patonce Cross symbol have any record of use in Hungary?

Tags: heraldry, money, hungary

Hungary introduced new 10000 HUF notes that contain a symbol I couldn't relate to Hungary's history. There were no official notes known to me why they use Patonce Cross on Hungarian notes.

[image]

And here is the symbol in question:

[image]

I found a few appearances of the same symbol in heraldry. These are from English coat of arms and Canada. I see no relation to Hungary, but I would assume if a symbol is used in the very middle of the note it should have some important meaning.

Comment: That specific part of the bill is part of the anti-counterfit scheme. According to http://www.mnb.hu/Root/MNB/Bankjegy_es_erme/bankjegyeink/u10000 and choose "Biztonsági elemek" you should get a popup. That specific design has a "A bankjegy előoldalának közepén található motívum mozgatás hatására aranyról zöld színűre változik, a két szín egyértelműen megkülönböztethető egymástól." Translates to "Pattern in the middle of the front side of the banknote is located a result of moving from gold turns green, the color of two clearly distinguishable from each other."

Comment: By the way, the symbol on the left-top looks like a Celtic Cross.

Comment: @CGCampbell yes, yes, I read it of course, I have no problem with the purpose, but why that kind of cross? I mean Hungary has an own cross type which is in the coat of arms, I see no point on using different symbolism. And as Anixx pointed out that symbol on the left-top is clearly not Hungarian origin. I see no connection to Hungarian history in these new notes' newly built in symbols. Maybe I am wrong and there is some distant relation or hidden fact which I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary In fact, I was sure you had, I just added it as a datapoint for any other researchers. That's why it is a comment and not an answer...it's not an answer to your question.